# Filebeat dial up error on localhost

Tags: filebeat, dialup, wazuh

So, I'm trying to configure Wazuh Server on a virtual machine (Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1) and it needs the filebeat (without Elastic) to work correctly. I've installed both sucessfully and enabled them via systemctl without any problem. but when I reach the test output phase, it simply returns me the following error:

```shell
    elasticsearch: https://127.0.0.1:9200...
      parse url... OK
      connection...
        parse host... OK
        dns lookup... OK
        addresses: 127.0.0.1
        dial up... ERROR dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9200: connect: connection refused
```

but there are no errors on my logs, and the services statuses are all okay...

Does anyone know what can cause this issue? Or have any clues on it?

[Installation Guide](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/wazuh-server/step-by-step.html)

[image: Wazuh Status]
[image: Filebeat Status]

Comment: Do you have elasticsearch? Is it listening on port 9200?

Comment: nope, they don't use it on wazuh configuration in the Server install guide.

Comment: I don't know Wazuh, but five minutes of googling (and your error messages) seems to indicate that Wazuh Manager depends on ES.

Comment: It's kinda strange, cuz on installation guide it only installs filebeat, but I'll install it and as soon as I can, I'll let u know :D

Comment: What guide are you following? [Edit] your question to contain *all* relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

So, following the tip from @vidarlo, I've installed Elasticsearch, it's fresh install resolved the dial up problem, but it caused a TLS handshake error, which was solved by editing `/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml` and changed the protocol it was using (from https to http), it solved all problems. :D

[Here's the guide I've used from Digital Ocean to install Elastic](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-22-04)